# EF Core Migrations manual edits possible?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-2.0

I am using EF Core 2.0 in my sample project with some value object configurations. I modify the code and generate migrations via CLI command line. In the last migration rather than adding a new database table as it should, it is trying to rename existing tables to each other and create an extra table for existing one. I could not figure out the reason for it.

Issue is, since with EF Core the snapshot is a separate auto-generated file from the migration itself I don't want to modify the snapshot.

I only want to modify the migration script so that it will not rename multiple tables, and then generate the snapshot from the migrations I created.

I did not see any command for this in the CLI - is it such a bad practice to modify the scaffolded migration and regenerate or am I missing some obvious new link where how to manually modify migration scripts is explained?

Thanks a bunch.

Update 1: After comments, added info about the snapshot from [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/migrations).

Because the current database schema is represented in code, EF Core doesn't have to interact with the database to create migrations. When you add a migration, EF determines what changed by comparing the data model to the snapshot file. EF interacts with the database only when it has to update the database. +

Comment: Aren't you able to just modify the file? It is located in Migrations folder if you didn't specify otherwise.

Comment: I am able to - yet doesn't this have risk of having snapshot become stale if I miss anything?  I would like to generate it from the migrations if possible and the framework to return me errors if the current state of code does not match the migrations combined.

Comment: @cassandrad And what happens if there is a discrepancy between snapshot and the files in that case? _ContextModelSnapshot file in the same folder what is the purpose of it if it is not used.

Comment: I don't really understand what do you call a snapshot. Can you elaborate? And if you'll change only script and don't change context's types of DbSet, you won't be able to rename the tables once again in normal way. So, if you want to rename the tables correctly, you need to rename types or set names with Fluent API.

Comment: @cassandrad please check the link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/migrations - From there: "Because the current database schema is represented in code, EF Core doesn't have to interact with the database to create migrations. When you add a migration, EF determines what changed by comparing the data model to the snapshot file. EF interacts with the database only when it has to update the database." - This is the snapshot file - I will update the question for clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the link, now I got it. Why you don't want to modify the snapshot? In any way, you need to make everything synchronized: database, snapshot and context. With EF core as I know, there is no information about schema in database anymore. So you can start with syncing snapshot and db. Then, if context differs from snapshot, synchronize context. And only then rename your tables. Looks like someone has changed context without creating migration and snapshot hasn't been updated correctly. Probably you can find that change, revert it and update snapshot with context in proper way.

Comment: Thanks @cassandrad - fully agree with you in that this is the correct approach. The problem is I am the only one changing the code - and I made it down to adding one atomic table before my last migration due to all those issues that I have seen (so there is only 1 added table). My main concern with changing both snapshot and code is that it kind-of defeats the purpose of changing at a single location and can cause hard to fix bugs as DB progresses if I miss something - so migrations don't add much more value in that case.

Comment: This sounds like something the team should investigate. Can you [submit a new issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/new)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I examined my generated snapshot code from source control. It exactly has added one extra table as what I needed.

The migration script to generate this is hectic at best - renaming multiple tables to each other and then warning that this could break causing multiple issues.

Since this is a sample project for me with only mock data as of now at least, I decided to go for it and not break the automated scripts. I am willing to lose some mock data at this stage rather than wasting time on it.

If this were in a production database I would be extremely careful to manually create the same result with intervention modifying both the scaffold and the migration file.

I am accepting this one as an answer (basically saying current EF Core does not support it to the best of my current knowledge) since there is no other candidate now - I will be more than glad to accept if any better answer shows up.